# How to put this filter function into an If function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function: http://jsfiddle.net/xznzyxyg/2/

Basically what it does it checks of the value of an input is equal to another value of another input in the same `div`.

Instead of the filtering I want it in an If function.
So that `if true{ colour red}`

The function I have now;

```
var inputs = $('#lol input');
var hoofdinput = document.getElementById('ad');
function Getred(i,el){
    return inputs.not(this).filter(function() {
        return hoofdinput.value === el.value;
    }).length !== 0;
}).addClass('red');
```

What I want it in:

```
If (true){
// Colour red
}
else {
Alert('No duplicates');
}
```

Can somebody help me with this, I'm really frustrated with this one...
Thanks!!

EDIT: This is the solution, duplicates are coloured with red and others which are not duplicate with green: http://jsfiddle.net/xznzyxyg/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is something like this what you are looking for?

```
var inputs = $('#lol input');
var hoofdinput = document.getElementById('ad');

for( var counter = 0; counter < inputs.length; counter++) {
    if ( hoofdinput.value === inputs[counter].value )
        inputs[counter].className += 'red';
    else
        alert('No duplicates');
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! With a bit of change I had it to my likings! Thanks, demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xznzyxyg/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var $inputs = $('div.myDiv input')

$inputs.each(function(i1, input1){
    $inputs.slice(i1 + 1).each(function(i2, input2) { 
        if (input1.value == input2.value) $(input2).addClass('red');
    });
});
```

Then if you need to alert that there were no matches

```
if ($('div.myDiv input.red').length == 0) alert('No duplicates');
```